# column passed error while putting a list in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this list :

```
20161216014500
20161216020000
20161216021500
20161216023000
20161216024500
20161216030000
20161216031500
20161216033000
20161216034500
20161216040000
20161216041500
20161216043000
20161216044500
20161216050000
20161216051500
20161216053000
20161216054500
```

And I want after parsing it and putting it in the correct format by this code:

```
for row in rows:
    if "".join(row).strip() != "":
        chaine = str(row[0]+row[1])
        date = chaine[:10] + " " + chaine[11:]
        header = parseDate(date)
        header = str(header).replace('-','')
        header = str(header).replace(':','')
        header = str(header).replace(' ','')
        print header
```

I want to insert the header(the list above) in a dataframe using pandas:

```
newDataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=header)
```

This is the error I get:

```
 14 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns
```

What is the reason of this error and how to correct it ?

Comment: Your code and data is incomplete, what is `data` here? additionally the error is clear, you're passing a list 14 columns but your data is a single column hence the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same thing this way:

```
import pandas as pd
rows = ['20161216014500',
'20161216020000',
'20161216021500',
'20161216023000',
'20161216024500',
'20161216030000',
'20161216031500',
'20161216033000',
'20161216034500',
'20161216040000',
'20161216041500',
'20161216043000',
'20161216044500',
'20161216050000',
'20161216051500',
'20161216053000',
'20161216054500']

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['date'])

pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

df
```

output:

```
    date
0   20161216014500
1   20161216020000
2   20161216021500
3   20161216023000
4   20161216024500
5   20161216030000
6   20161216031500
7   20161216033000
8   20161216034500
9   20161216040000
10  20161216041500
11  20161216043000
12  20161216044500
13  20161216050000
14  20161216051500
15  20161216053000
16  20161216054500
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

a = io.StringIO(u"""20161216014500
20161216020000
20161216021500
20161216023000
20161216024500
20161216030000
20161216031500
20161216033000
20161216034500
20161216040000
20161216041500
20161216043000
20161216044500
20161216050000
20161216051500
20161216053000
20161216054500""")

df = pd.read_csv(a, header=None, parse_dates=[0],
                       date_parser=pd.tseries.tools.parse_time_string)
df.head()
```

Output:

```
                    0
0 2016-12-16 01:45:00
1 2016-12-16 02:00:00
2 2016-12-16 02:15:00
3 2016-12-16 02:30:00
4 2016-12-16 02:45:00
```